# how to remove whitespace from explode

Tags: php

how will i eliminate the white space when the value is empty? i used this codes i also try to trim it but it does not work how should i do this ? thank you in advance.

Here is the picture

[image]

```
    $imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);
    $imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);

    foreach($imeiserial as $is){
    $imeicode = trim($is);

    if (in_array($is,$imeitransferserial)) {
          $select = 'selected="selected" ';
     }
     else {
           $select = "";
     }
    echo "<option ".$select."value='$imeicode'>".$imeicode."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the input you're getting, the result you want to get for it, and the result you're actually getting?

Comment: if (!$imeicode) continue;

Comment: the value is empty it should not select any value but in my problem it gives me space value to select

Comment: Fact: There is never any benefit in declaring an `<option>`'s `value` attribute if it is identical to the option's text.  No benefit to any client-side languages at all.  The result is only unnecessarily bloated markup -- just remove the declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of array_map and array_filter, or possibly just array_filter, will do the trick.

array_map with trim will remove extra whitespaces:

```
$imeitransferserial = array_map('trim',$imeitransferserial );
```

array_filter will remove empty elements from the array:

```
$imeitransferserial = array_filter($imeitransferserial);
```

If you can have a value of 0 in the array, you will want to use strlen as a callback for array_filter:

```
$imeitransferserial = array_filter($imeitransferserial, 'strlen');
```

By default, array_filter will remove anything that evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);
$imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);

$imeitransferserial =array_map('trim',$imeitransferserial );
//print_r($imeitransferserial);

$imeiserial = array_filter($imeiserial);
foreach ($imeiserial as $is) {
    $imeicode = trim($is);

    if (in_array($is, $imeitransferserial)) {
        $select = 'selected="selected" ';
    } else {
        $select = "";
    }
    echo "<option " . $select . "value='$imeicode'>" . $imeicode . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$imeitransferserial = array_filter(explode(',', $imeitransfer), 'trim');
$imeiserial = array_filter(explode(',', $imei), 'trim');
```

Comment: Trim is a  pretty strange callback for array_filter.  It will work in this example, but it's extra work for no reason versus just the default functionality since you won't actually be able to make use of the trimmed value.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!